# How I get only one User of a List

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a question and I don't find the solution for it :(

I have a ASP.NEt Application that get Data from a Active Directory. I build a 3-tier Application. I have a Model Project that have a User Class ("Benutzer.cs") and a Data layer and Service Layer. 
In my Data layer I get the Informations about a user in AD. I want now get only one User and my question is how i can filter one User of a List. Maybe a stupid question but I don't know what I must do :D

My Code:

```
...

                    IUserService srv = new UserService();
                    List<Model.Benutzer> usr = srv.GetUser(Domain, null, null, UserID); 

                        // I want the one User of this List can I found this User about
                        //  Benutzer User = usr.? 

                    ...
```

I want only one User. This is the Code of my getUser method:

```
public List<Benutzer> GetUser(string Domain, string Benutzer, string Werk, string GUID)
        {
            List<Benutzer> result = new List<Benutzer>();

                DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<GUID=" + GUID + ">");

                string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn=*))"; 

                DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);

                   SearchResult res = Searcher.FindOne();

                    result.Add(new Benutzer()
                    {
                        Benutzername = GetProperty(res, "sAMAccountName"),
                        Vorname = GetProperty(res, "givenName"),
                        Nachname = GetProperty(res, "sn"),
                        eMail = GetProperty(res, "mail"),
                        Unternehmen = GetProperty(res, "company"),
                        Abteilung = GetProperty(res, "Department"),
                        Raum = GetProperty(res, "physicalDeliveryOfficeName"),
                        Beschreibung = GetProperty(res, "Description"),
                        Kostenstelle = GetProperty(res, "extensionAttribute3"),
                        Telefonnummer = GetProperty(res, "telephoneNumber"),
                        Mobilnummer = GetProperty(res, "mobile"),
                        Haustelefon = GetProperty(res, "homePhone"),
                        Fax = GetProperty(res, "facsimileTelephoneNumber"),
                        Pager = GetProperty(res, "pager"),
                        Standort = GetProperty(res, "l")
                    });

            return result; 
        }
```

tarasov

Comment: Why do you make and return a `List<>` to begin with?

Comment: I need a List for my ListView but I have in my ListView in every row a Button and if I click on the Button I change the Webform to the Main Information about the User.

Comment: but I have the solution now :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code should be returning only one user in the list.  DirectorySearcher.FindOne returns only the first entry found.

If you want to not return it in a list, make the return value Benutzer and then result should be of type Benutzer as well:

```
public Benutzer GetUser(string Domain, string Benutzer, string Werk, string GUID)
{
    Benutzer result = new Benutzer();
    DirectoryEntry Entry = new DirectoryEntry("LDAP://<GUID=" + GUID + ">");
    string filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(objectCategory=person)(cn=*))";

    DirectorySearcher Searcher = new DirectorySearcher(Entry, filter);
    SearchResult res = Searcher.FindOne();
    result =new Benutzer()
    {
        Benutzername = GetProperty(res, "sAMAccountName"),
        Vorname = GetProperty(res, "givenName"),
        Nachname = GetProperty(res, "sn"),
        eMail = GetProperty(res, "mail"),
        Unternehmen = GetProperty(res, "company"),
        Abteilung = GetProperty(res, "Department"),
        Raum = GetProperty(res, "physicalDeliveryOfficeName"),
        Beschreibung = GetProperty(res, "Description"),
        Kostenstelle = GetProperty(res, "extensionAttribute3"),
        Telefonnummer = GetProperty(res, "telephoneNumber"),
        Mobilnummer = GetProperty(res, "mobile"),
        Haustelefon = GetProperty(res, "homePhone"),
        Fax = GetProperty(res, "facsimileTelephoneNumber"),
        Pager = GetProperty(res, "pager"),
        Standort = GetProperty(res, "l")
    };              

    return result;  
}
```

Comment: Thanks! :) It works...I thought I can get a User from the List but this way is better

Comment: @Tarasov you *can* get the user from the list (see my answer), however, if your method will/should only return a single user then there is no point in returning a list.

Answer (score 1):

If you are only after one user then update your `GetUser` method to return a single user instance rather than a list:

```
public Benutzer GetUser(...)
{
    ....
    return new Benutzer(...);
}
```

If you have no control over the `GetUser` method and just want to extract the user from the list returned then call:

```
srv.GetUser(Domain, null, null, UserID).FirstOrDefault();
```